# Find the indexes of several elements in a list

Tags: python, arrays

I have an list of integers:

```
 x = [0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 33, 39, 49, 51, 11, 
      32, 55, 61, 31, 44, 43, 4, 45, 30, 50, 41]
```

And second list that can only contain elements from `x`,
for example: `y = [44, 11, 49]`

I need to find the index of each element of `y` in `x`.

Comment: Those aren't arrays. They are lists. What have you tried?

Comment: Please post your expected output. Also, what if `y` contains an element that is not in `x`?

Comment: Does list x contains any duplicates?

Comment: `indexes = [x.index(element) for element in y]`

Comment: x doesn't contain duplicates. y cant contain an element that in not in x.

Comment: This should be re-opened, linked questions concern single search while the goal here is to find several values.

Answer (score 1):

.index() is what you're after.

```
x = [0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 33, 39, 49, 51, 11, 32, 55, 61, 31, 44, 43, 4, 45, 30, 50, 41]
y = [44, 11, 49]
for a in y:
    print(x.index(a))
```

EDIT: Provided that each element of y appears once, and only once in x.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 33, 39, 49, 51, 11, 32, 55, 61, 31, 44, 43, 4, 45, 30, 50, 41]
y = [44, 11, 49]
indexs=[x.index(i) for i in y if i in x]
print(indexs)
```

Or

```
ind=list(map(x.index,y))
print(ind)
```